# Creating levels for binary variable?

Tags: r

So I want to create levels for the binary variable of in this case "school type" 0 stands for public schools and 1 stands for private schools.
My code is:

```
levels(d0$public.private) <- c("public","private")
```

I assumed that this changes the data set from zeros and ones to public and private however I ran the code and checked and it still shows the zeros and ones.

[image: Picture of data head]

Comment: Try this `d0$public.private <- c("0" = "public", "1" = "private")[as.character(d0$public.private)]`

Answer (score 0):

You can't see them but they're there, try:

```
d0$public.private
```